# Could not load file or assembly error even when the old DLL was renamed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

In my VS 2013 solution, I have few projects like:

1. BookService.BusinessLogic
2. BookServiceContracts
3. BookJob

The BookJob project is a console application which references the services: BookService.BusinessLogic and BookServiceContracts. The INetPub folder contains DLLs of BookService.BusinessLogic and these are invoked when job is executed.

The application was working fine. Recently there was a requirement to add a code in BookService.BusinessLogic project. I added the code, recompiled and replaced the BookService.BusinessLogic.DLL and BookService.BusinessLogic.pdb in INetPub. This is when the problem started. The EventViewer is logging errors something like this:

> Exception=The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response
> message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;
> charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
> IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024
> bytes of the response were: '
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'BookService.BusinessLogic_old'
> or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
> does not match the assembly reference.

I renamed the previous DLL in InetPub folder as BookService.BusinessLogic_old, but the job is still pointing to the old DLL it seems. How to fix this reference issue?

Comment: try renaming BookService.BusinessLogic.dll.old, or delete the old dll completely and see whether it works, when you have more than 1 dll with same namespace would cause issues,

Comment: @coder_b Is there a possibility that the job BookJob is also referencing the project's bin folder and InetPub as well ? Because the bin folder of BookService.BusinessLogic contains the older version. I only replaced in the INetPub.

Comment: for console app better check it is referencing the new dll, when you compile or build it automatically copies the new references to bin folder.

Comment: @coder_b I will make both the versions same. In InetPub as well as Bin folder.